# How to get properties from feature without event listener? (event.feature)

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

how to get the "feature" data from a layer (loaded with geoJSON) without event listener?

**thats the usual way, which works fine:**

```
layer1.addListener('mouseover', function (event) {
    console.log( event.feature.getProperty('description') );
}
```

but now i want to get the value from data object "layer1".

**i tried already this:**

```
layer1.getProperty('description')
layer1.feature.getProperty('description')
```

**The way how i load the geoJSON**

```
var layer1 = new google.maps.Data();
layer1 = loadGeoJson('https://googledrive.com/host/MYFILE')
```

**The content of json**

*Here a short question btw: if i have more features (e.g polygons) in my json, can i get this values to manipulate (e.g. toggle visibility) it?*

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    12.3456789,
                    01.2345678,
                    0
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "name": "Test Polygon",
                "description": "My Test Description"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the features of a [google.maps.Data](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data) Layer, use:

> **forEach(callback:function(Data.Feature))**
>
> Return Value:  None
>
> Repeatedly invokes the given function, passing a feature in the collection to the function on each invocation. The order of iteration through the features is undefined.

or to get a single feature (if you know the Id):

> **getFeatureById(id:number|string)**
>
> Return Value:  Data.Feature|undefined
>
> Returns the feature with the given ID, if it exists in the collection. Otherwise returns undefined.
>
> Note that the IDs 1234 and '1234' are equivalent. Either can be used to look up the same feature.